# Pushforward of a line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ to a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles, line-bundles, algebraic-k-theory

In his notes on K-theory, A. Okounkov states the following exercise:

The group $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{P}^1$ and on line bundles $\mathcal{O}(k)$ over it.  Push forward these line bundles under $\pi\colon\mathbb{P}^1 \to \text{ pt}$ using an explicit $T$-invariant ($T$ is supposed to be the maximal torus in $\operatorname{GL}(2)$) Čech covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

The pushforward is defined as:

$$\pi_*\mathcal{O}(k) = \sum_i (-1)^i [R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}(k)].$$

If $\mathbb{P}^1$ is given by the coordinates $x_0,x_1$, the Čech covering $$U_1 = \{y_1 = x_1/x_0 \mid x_0\neq 0\}, U_2 = \{z_0 = x_0/x_1 \mid x_1\neq 0\}$$ is $T$-invariant.

By Theorem II.8.5 in Hartshorne,

$$R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}(k) = H^i(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(k))^\sim.$$

How do I conclude and where does the action come into play?

Comment: What do you want to conclude?

Comment: What the push forward of these line bundles under $\pi\colon\mathbb{P}^1 \to \text{ pt}$ is (using an explicit $T$-invariant Čech covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Comment: The pushforward is determined by the two formulas in your question. The \v{C}ech covering is a tool that can be used to compute the cohomology, providing an alternative to the argument from Hartshorne. The action itself plays no role for this computation, but it is useful to observe that the result is also valid in the $\mathrm{GL}(2)$-equivariant category.

Comment: Thanks. How would one compute $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}(k)$ using the covering?

Comment: By means of Čech resolution, of course.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{C}^0(U,\mathcal{O}(d)) = \iota_*(\mathcal{O}(d)|_{U_0})$ and $\mathcal{C}^1(U,\mathcal{O}(d)) = \iota_*(\mathcal{O}(d)|_{U_0\cap U_1})$ correct? ($\iota$ being some inclusion from an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_cohomology