# Minimal polynomial of $\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes -$-operator

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, minimal-polynomials, algebraic-k-theory, equivariant-cohomology

This is somewhat of a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4596983/pushforward-of-a-line-bundle-on-mathbbp1-to-a-point?noredirect=1#comment9682903_4596983) question.

Take $X= \mathbb{P}^1, G = \operatorname{GL}(2)$. Compute the minimal polynomial
of the operator $\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes -$ on $K_G(X)$.

How does one do this?

Comment: $K_G(X)$ is the $G$-invariant Grothendieck group of $X$?

Comment: It's the $G$-equivariant $K$-theory of $X$ (coherent sheaves, not vector bundles).